# Custom validator not working correctly in Angular reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

New to Angular and trying to add a custom email validator that will go to my server and check if the email address is already in use.

But can't seem to get the error message displaying on form.
Here is how I'm testing it before I attempt to hit the server.

FYI - the "emailMatchValidator()" is called but I can't get it to display any kind of error message on the form!

Maybe I should try something other than .touched!

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.createRegisterForm();
  }

createRegisterForm() {
  this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
    gender: ['male'],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(10)]],
    knownAs: ['', Validators.required],
    dateOfBirth: [null, Validators.required],
    city: ['', Validators.required],
    country: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(8)]],
    confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
  }, {
    validator: [this.passwordMatchValidator, this.emailMatchValidator]
  });
}

emailMatchValidator(g: FormGroup) {
  return g.get('email').value !== 'emailaddress@gmail.com' ? null : {
    emailExists: true
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" 
                        [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': registerForm.get('email').errors && registerForm.get('email').touched}
                          || registerForm.get('email').touched && registerForm.hasError('emailExists')"
                        class="form-control" 
                        formControlName="email" 
                        placeholder="Email">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').touched && registerForm.get('email').hasError('required')">
                          Email is required
                        </div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').touched && registerForm.get('email').hasError('email')">
                          Invalid email address
                        </div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').touched && registerForm.get('email').hasError('emailExists')">
                            Email address already in use
                          </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made some changes:

- You had applied the validation to the complete form, i changed that to the email field only `email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.emailMatchValidator]],`;
- Added the email field value & email field status to the screen to see the validation in action
- enter anything in the email field and move focus to get the validation in action

relevant **HTML**:

```
    <form class="form-group" [formGroup]='registerForm'>
        <input type="email" 
                        [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': registerForm.get('email').errors && registerForm.get('email').touched}
                          || registerForm.get('email').touched && registerForm.hasError('emailExists')"
                        class="form-control" 
                        formControlName="email" 
                        placeholder="Email">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').touched && registerForm.get('email').hasError('required')">
                          Email is required
                        </div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').touched && registerForm.get('email').hasError('email')">
                          Invalid email address
                        </div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').touched && registerForm.get('email').hasError('emailExists')">
                            Email address already in use
                          </div>
                    </form>

<hr/>
                    <b>email value:</b> {{registerForm.controls.email.value}} <br/>
                    <b>email status:</b> {{registerForm.controls.email.status}}
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  registerForm;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createRegisterForm();
    console.log(this.registerForm);
  }

  createRegisterForm() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      gender: ['male'],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.emailMatchValidator]],
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(10)]],
      knownAs: ['', Validators.required],
      dateOfBirth: [null, Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      country: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(8)]],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
    }
      /*, {
          validator: [this.passwordMatchValidator, this.emailMatchValidator]
        }
        */
    );
  }

  passwordMatchValidator() {
    /* some implementation */
  }

  emailMatchValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control.value !== 'emailaddress@gmail.com') {
      return false;
    } else {
      return { emailExists: true };
    }
  }

}
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udxqfb)

Comment: thanks for the help! Quick question - as this project isn't mine, and I'm still learning, why did the developer use a "validator: this.passwordMatchValidator" on the complete form? Is it because he's attempting to validate accross multiple controls (password, confirmPassword) ?